# bitcoin and blockchain dev options

Tags: python, bitcoin, blockchain

I don't know if this is the best place to ask this, but I'm not looking for help on a specific problem. I'm looking into block chain technology and some bit coin stuff. Ran into someone that does a lot of articles on the subject and was curious about it.

Since its new(ish) technology and still up and coming, I'm wonder if it would be interesting to get involved somehow and help shape and/or add to it in some way.

What types of development is going on out there on this technology these days. All the reading material I can find online related to development and block chain is 4+years old. I'm sure its much different today. Anyone know of some good resources for learning about the technology, what type of development opportunities there are (python preferred) and just general info?

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic

Comment: This question is off-topic for several reasons, most primarily because it's based entirely on asking for speculation and opinion about the future of Bitcoin and its evolution and value over time, which is by no means a programming related question. Please spend some time reviewing the [help] pages, particularly [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What kinds of question should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that as a developer you will be interested in smart-contract. [Ethereum](http://ethereum.org) with it's Solidity as the most well-known platform which offers smart-contracts is a good point to start. Check out frameworks built on top of Ethereum like [truffle](https://github.com/etherlab/truffle) as well

I think that as developers the best thing we can do now is to develop some applications which simplifies using of blockchain for people because it's still looks like stuff for geeks.

May be you an idea of web-service which will be much better in case of using blockchain and smart-contracts? Great! Create MVP, get expertise in the area, show your product, talk to people and go on.

Answer (score 0):

BitCoin is already pretty much hit its peak. The price of BitCoin is now dropping, and all you can find about it is already online. The BitCoin chains that you are looking for is pretty much used by connecting a bunch of Raspberry Pis that run the BitCoin mining program on it. The more you have, the faster you will mine the BitCoins, and you will profit from it. However, BitCoin mining is very hard to do, and it takes a very long time. You waste more money using electricity than actually getting the BitCoins. I'm sorry if you already know this information, and you still want to mine BitCoins. But this is all I have to say about this topic (Trust me, I've tried to do it --  and it's tough).

Comment: hey thanks, I'm not interested in mining at all. I read about it to learn and agree with all your points. I was more leaning toward the underlying technology and what can be done with it in the future and actual development of new apps/webapps etc. Would major corporations start looking towards blockchain etc..